# laravel sociallite in boilerplate

Tags: laravel, authentication, boilerplate

I have used laravel boilerplate for login.
I have worked using virtual host and put information on basis of virtualhost.

I have 2 tables:

```
 1. users
 2. social_logins
```

Actually i am authenticating from `users` table. I need to store information in `users` and then link it with `social_logins` `user_id` i.e, store information in table 2.

The main problem here is it doesn't store data in table. This line is not working:

```
return $this->getAuthorizationFirst($provider);
```

I have put redirect so it will redirect to given route but doesn't store data in database.

if I catch callback in controller I can catch the information.

```
 $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

I have done normally using Socialite plugin in normal laravel, but i don't have any idea in Boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Actual lifecycle of this `loginThirdParty` trait is:
**1** The first time this is hit, request is empty
**2** It's redirected to the provider and then back here, where request is populated
**3** So it then continues creating the user

So If the provider is not an acceptable, this trait kick back. Hopefully you need to recheck your .env for `FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID, FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET and CALLBACK_URL`.